# Auto-Boot to Desktop Makes Pi auto login to "Pi" User

Tags: software-compatibility

I wanted my RPI to boot to the GUI so I set it up in raspi-config. However, now it boots into the pi user without a password. Is there a way to make it boot to a login screen where you can choose a user to login to?

**EDIT** I was confused I didn't mean startx. I went to raspi-config window and chose boot to desktop and it is giving me this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=27346) over at Raspberrypi.org, you need to modify lightdm.conf (/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf). There is an "autologin-user" parameter in that conf file that you can modify, and, paraphrasing the last poster, several other setting you need to change:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^greeter-hide-users=true/greeter-hide-users=false/g' /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
sudo sed -i 's/^\#greeter-allow-guest=true/greeter-allow-guest=false/g' /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
sudo sed -i 's/^\#greeter-show-manual-login=false/greeter-show-manual-login=true/g' /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
sudo sed -i 's/^\#allow-guest=true/allow-guest=false/g' /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
sudo sed -i 's/^\#allow-guest=true/allow-guest=false/g' /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
sudo sed -i 's/^\#autologin-user-timeout=0/autologin-user-timeout=10/g' /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
# also comment out default login from 'pi'
sudo sed -i 's/^autologin-user=pi/\#autologin-user=pi/g' /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did each of these in the command prompt and it still did not work after reboot! Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to confirm - you are doing this in Raspbian, latest version? And after making the above changes, you boot into the GUI but there is no user authentication screen, just direct booting into the Pi desktop environment?

Comment: Correct...exactly ;-)